# XML value is not getting into the variables

Tags: xml, web-services, api, curl, soap

When I try to print or retrieve xml response by using a request through another xml is not showing. the code is below. I want this code connect with a soap api and display data from the api, and the data is in xml, but I didn't get the data.

```
 <?php 
   if($_REQUEST['submit']){


     //Data, connection, auth
    //$dataFromTheForm = $_POST['fieldName']; // request data from the form
    $soapUrl = "http://testapi.roombookpro.com/en/soap/index"; // asmx URL of WSDL
    $soapUser = "testapi@roombookpro.com";  //  username
    $soapPassword = "password@123"; // password

    // xml post structure


    $xml_post_string = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fram="http://framework.zend.com">
                        <soapenv:Header/>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                        <fram:search>
                        <securityInfo>
                        <!-- You may enter the following 4 items in any order  -->
                        <userName>username</userName>
                        <password>password</password>
                        <agentCode>agentcode</agentCode>
                        <lang>en</lang>
                        </securityInfo>
                        <currency>INR</currency>
                        <city>DEL</city>
                        <checkInDate>2017-02-01</checkInDate>
                        <checkOutDate>2017-02-01</checkOutDate>
                        <rooms>
                        <!-- You may enter the following 4 items in any order  -->
                        <room1>
                        <!-- You may enter the following 6 items in any order  -->
                        <adults>2</adults>
                        <childAge1>2</childAge1>
                        </room1>
                        </rooms>
                        <rating>1</rating>
                        <availableOnly>true</availableOnly>
                        <nationality>IN</nationality>
                        <payType>all</payType>
                        <agentMarkup>0</agentMarkup>
                        </fram:search>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                        </soapenv:Envelope>';   // data from the form, e.g. some ID number

       $headers = array(
                    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    "Accept: text/xml",
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                    "Pragma: no-cache",
                    //"SOAPAction: http://testapi.roombookpro.com/en/soap/index#search", 
                    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
                ); //SOAPAction: your op URL

        $url = $soapUrl;

        // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword); // username and password - declared at the top of the doc
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        // converting
        $response = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);

        // converting
        $response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
        $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);


        // convertingc to XML



        //$parser = simplexml_load_string($response);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
        foreach ($xml->xpath('//ns2:Soap_Model_SOAP_Location_Country') as $item)
        {
            print_r($item);
 //to access individual elements 
//        echo $item->id ;
//        echo $item ->code;
//        echo $item->name;
//        echo "\n";

        }
   }
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two problems:

1. **checkInDate** and  **checkOutDate** are far future and your API
   seems doesnot support it.
2. your xpath is seems wrong, you may need to
   change it to `Soap_Model_SOAP_Hotel_Hotel`

tested with following dates:

```
<checkInDate>2016-10-05</checkInDate>
<checkOutDate>2016-10-09</checkOutDate>
```

and xpath:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//ns2:Soap_Model_SOAP_Hotel_Hotel') as $item)
```

i am getting some results.

Comment: thank you its working. but there are some more error, but I'll try to catch it, if I can't Ill back with you.. :) :)

Comment: when I use this code, I cant access to the images, :(